Inside our Fork GitHub repository, how we can manage our changes with future releases done by the upstream, incase our files get modified by upstream
I worked on many projects for building SPFx from scratch, and posting the code to GitHub, but I always own the SPFx, so I have full control on my code and future release.
Now I am working on modifying an SPFx that was developed by other contributors at https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-emergency-operations-center.
Now I will do the following:

Fork the repository

Apply our modifications which mainly include modifying the fields Labels and Description, mainly by modifying LocaleStrings.ts file.

Also, the current solution will create Assessment channel when a new incident item gets created. But in our case we need to create 5 additional channels and remove the Assessment channel. So, I will add the new methods to create the additional channels inside the following IncidentDetais.tsx file:



Everything is somehow easy to me from the coding part. But how can I keep my Fork repository in sync with future updates from the upstream? Let's say in a future release done by the upstream they also modify the IncidentDetais.tsx by adding more channels, then how we can get those updates and at the same time keeps our modifications? Is there a way to do this or we will need to manually merge our changes to the updated IncidentDetais.tsx file?
How will the life cycle be?

This is the entire point of git merge.  Is there a reason that won't work?

@StephenNewell thanks for the reply. but how merge will generally work? For example, when I remove the method for creating the Assessment channel, and i added 5 new methods to create the additional 5 channels? and i renamed the "News" tab into "Announcements" .. and then the upstream did their own modifications to the same file, then how the merge will apply my modifications and the upstream modification without any conflict ?

If there are conflicts, git merge will mark them and you'll have to resolve them.  I don't know anything about spfx, but why wouldn't it work just like any other file?

@StephenNewell Thanks again for your help . yes at the end SPFx has .ts  files nothing special about them.. so at the end when there is conflict in a single file it will be my responsibility to manually merge the changes i did and the changes inside the update >> test them locally >> and redeploy to our catalog.. is this generally the process ?

That's exactly the process.  If you haven't used git merge before, there are lots of guides online and questions here about specific usage, so you shouldn't have any trouble finding an answer if you're dealing with merge conflicts or anything else that comes up.

@StephenNewell ok thanks, if you feel it is necessary, please add your comments as an answer so i can accept it, to be beneficial for others
